# How Scala's multiple parameter lists get encoded into JVM bytecode

Tags: java, scala, bytecode

In Scala, the following two function is different:

```
def paren(): Int = 42
def noparen: Int = 42
```

The first one has 1 parameter list with zero parameters, whereas the next one has 0 parameter list.

However, their bytecode is identical when viewed with `javap -v`:

```
public int paren();
  Signature: ()I
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: bipush        42
       2: ireturn
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
             0       3     0  this   LParentheses$;
    LineNumberTable:
      line 4: 0

public int noparen();
  Signature: ()I
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: bipush        42
       2: ireturn
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
             0       3     0  this   LParentheses$;
    LineNumberTable:
      line 5: 0
```

Where does the Scala compiler store the dimension of parameter lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test this, I used the following code, and `javap -v` as you did.

```
@Deprecated //add an annotation for reference
class Test {
  def test: Unit = ???
  def test2(): Unit = ???
}
```

at the very end, there is this output:

```
SourceFile: "Test.scala"
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #6()
  1: #7(#8=s#9)
Error: unknown attribute
  ScalaSig: length = 0x3
   05 00 00
```

Where `#6` is `@Deprecated` and `#7(#8=s#9)` is `@scala.reflect.ScalaSignature(bytes=...)`. So, even though there are multiple methods, and the class has its own signature as well, there is only one `ScalaSignature` annotation that encodes all the additional signature information in some binary format.

You already pointed to [SID-10](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sid/10) in your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32081920/371191), where it states that the signature is compressed (which is rather obvious, given that there are no recognizable class names in there), and that the `ScalaSig` class file attribute was used for this prior to Scala 2.8. (The reason for the change is explained to be reflection access at runtime - (at least unknown) attributes are not preserved by the JVM; annotations with proper retention are.)

One additional thing to note is that, while Scala signatures are a superset of Java signatures, the Java signatures still have to be unique - at runtime, the JVM doesn't care about Scala.

---

PS: this is also done in other JVM languages; one where I know it's definitely the case is AspectJ. I think generics could have been implemented this way as well, but they're not; they have their own encoding in the class file format.

Comment: Martin Odersky designed and implemented Generics during the Java 1.0 timeframe, in fact, the Java compiler he wrote was already shipped with 1.2 (and is still the one shipped with Oracle JDK and OpenJDK), just with the Generics bits disabled. Annotations were only added in Java 5. If Annotations had existed back then, or Generics had been (re-)designed later, who knows, maybe we'd have reified Generics by now.

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not explicitly mention it,

[SID-10](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sid/10) suggests that those information would be stored in ScalaSignature.